# View not found - asp.net mvc error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, view, error-handling

I am getting an error saying the view Update has not been found, I wanted to show the TaskDetail view not the update view...

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Update(int taskid, string status)
    {
        if (!status.Equals("closed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            !status.Equals("opened", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "incorrect status, please try again");

        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
            return TaskDetail(taskid);

        if (status.Equals("Closed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            _service.CloseTask( taskid, true);
        else
            _service.CloseTask(taskid, false);

        this.FlashInfo("success, task status has been updated...");
        return RedirectToAction("TaskDetail");
```

}

Exception:

```
$exception{"The view 'Update' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:\r\n~/Areas/Tasks/Views/TaskManager/Update.aspx\r\n~/Areas/Tasks/Views/TaskManager/Update.ascx\r\n~/Areas/Tasks/Views/Shared/Update.aspx\r\n~/Areas/Tasks/Views/Shared/Update.ascx\r\n~/Views/TaskManager/Update.aspx\r\n~/Views/TaskManager/Update.ascx\r\n~/Views/Shared/Update.aspx\r\n~/Views/Shared/Update.ascx"} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

Task Detail: (this is inside the same controller)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TaskDetail(int taskid)
    {
        var loggedonuser = _repo.GetCurrentUser();


        var companies = _repo.All<Company>();
        var users = _repo.All<User>();

        var task = _repo.Single<InstructionTask>
            (x => x.TaskID == taskid && (x.CompanyID == loggedonuser.CompanyID || x.AssignedTo.Contains(loggedonuser.CompanyType.ToString())));

        var dto = new TaskDTO
        {
            TaskID = task.TaskID,
            Title = task.Title,
            Description = task.Description,
            DateCreated = task.DateCreated,
            IsClosed = task.IsClosed,
            CompanyID = companies.Where(y => task.CompanyID == y.CompanyID).SingleOrDefault().Identifier,
        };

        var checkedtags = TaskTagsHelper.GetTags(task.AssignedTo);

        var t = TaskTagsHelper.GetPanelTags();

        if (checkedtags != null) //if tags are present only then tick them off...
        {
            foreach (var item in t.Keys.ToList())
            {
                if (checkedtags.Any(x => x == item))
                    t[item] = true;
            }
        }

        dto.AvailableTags = t;

        if (task.DueDate.HasValue)
            dto.DueDate = task.DueDate.Value;

        var comments = _repo.All<TaskComment>()
            .Where(x => x.TaskID == task.TaskID)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
            .Select(x => new TaskCommentDTO
            {
                Comment = x.Comment,
                Timestamp = x.Timestamp,
                CompanyID = companies.Where(y => x.CompanyID == y.CompanyID).SingleOrDefault().Identifier,
                UserID = users.Where(y => x.UserID == y.UserID).SingleOrDefault().Login,
                Type = EnumHelper.Convert<TaskCommentType>(x.Type)
            });

        dto.AllComments = comments;

        return View(new TaskViewModel
        {
            TaskDetail = dto,
            NewComment = new TaskCommentDTO()
        });
    }
```

I am catching the exception here in my base controller:

```
    //Generic methods/ controllers/ attributes will be applied here...
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        //dont interfere if the exception is already handled
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
            return;

        //let the next request know what went wrong
        filterContext.Controller.TempData["exception"] = filterContext.Exception;

        //logg exception

        //set up redirect to my global error handler
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "~/Views/Error/PublicError.aspx" };

        //advise subsequent exception filters not to interfere and stop
        // asp.net from showing yellow screen of death
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        //erase any output already generated
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of your code, you are calling the TaskDetail action from the Update method.  This is not recommended.  Here is why:

1. The owning context of the request is the Update method, which is why it's trying to render the "Update" view.  That is because by convention the view is selected based on the first action that is hit.  MVC is unaware that you've called TaskDetail.
2. It's a violation of the PRG pattern (Post-Redirect-Get).  I suggest you read up on this here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get - Basically, you really shouldn't render anything out from an HTTP POST.  You should redirect back to a GET.  It causes all sorts of problems not doing this.

If you want it working as it is, you can do this by changing the last line of the TaskDetail to the following so that it knows to always render the TaskDetail view, but I do not recommend it:

```
return View("TaskDetail", ...viewModel...)
```

Comment: How would I populate the modelstate errors if I do a redirect? The errors are lost right? the model state becomes 'valid' again, so to speak???

Comment: You don't do a redirect if your model state is invalid. You just show them the form again.

Comment: You should put the ModelState in TempData, then redirect to the GET and recover it.  There is a whole framework that handles all that for you described here, so you don't have to worry about managing it yourself: http://www.weirdlover.com/2010/07/21/the-big-boy-mvc-series-part-25-going-postal-actionfilters-moq-modelstate-oh-my/

Comment: Basically your TaskDetail view will have something like a TaskDetailViewModel strongly typed model associated with it. In your TaskDetail controller action it will populate this model and return it to the View like: TaskDetailViewModel model = new TaskDetailViewModel(); return View(model); If your model state is not valid on the POST to Update, you will just recreate your model and return the view, but since you are POSTing to Update, you need to specify the view this time: return View("TaskDetail", model);

Comment: @Dismissile: you are incorrect.  You should put it in TempData and redirect.  What happens if you press F5, or use the back button if you render something during a POST verb?  Play with it and see.

Comment: @Chris Smith: You are POSTing in the first place. You shouldn't put it in TempData and redirect. What happens when they refresh at that point? They lose all their data. If I POST the form and have invalid information, I shouldn't be redirected at that point. It should redisplay the form and redirect on success.

Comment: @Dismissile I have the same concern, I dont want my data to be lost... By the way how popular or widely used is the approach described by chris?

Comment: @Dismissile: No you don't lose the *data* - once it's populated after the redirect (from TempData!!!), the browser will remember it if you whack F5 as that is then the default state of the form at the point of the first GET in the PRG cycle.  You will lose some model state but that's deterministic and easily regenerated from the Model data.  Seriously go read up on PRG pattern and how it's applied to ASP.Net MVC - it's pretty awful to not use it.

Comment: @Haroon: it is considered best practice to follow the PRG pattern.  Google for ASP.Net MVC best practices.  Stackoverflow uses it everywhere as well!!!

Comment: No. You should only redirect on success. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538005/post-redirect-get-in-asp-net-mvc-and-validation-with-restful-urls

Comment: @Dismissile: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx ... http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx ... etc etc

Comment: @Chris Smith: What I mean is this. Let's say I want to edit a detail record. I go to the Edit action and then try to change the First Name field. I change it to be Foobar and then POST the form. I have a business rule that says that first name can not be Foobar. In your example you would shove this model in TempData and redirect back to the Edit. My First Name textbox says Foobar but then I hit refresh and now it is back to the original. This is not what you want.

Comment: It isn't if in the GET, you load the model state initially from tempdata if available which is what we do and is suggested by people.  The browser will persist the initial state client side.  Try it :)

Comment: @chris - I have tried this, I can verify you can successfuly post and be redirected back to get request, the temp data does work correctly... the posted data loads up with errors. If I hit refresh again (by acccident) all the data is then lost, I guess that is because I am on a get request? I guess I have to get used to pressing the "submit" button once again right?

Comment: Yeah I just verified this as well. Following your first link example using his attributes. It redirects and the model state shows the error and what I first posted. I hit refresh and BLAM, everything goes away.

Comment: I'll knock up a test rig when I get a few mins and stick it on bitbucket to demonstrate.  We've got 70+ controllers and 500+ actions that work fine with this ironically...  Keep your eyes peeled - might not be until after the weekend.

Comment: @Dismissile or chris- do you think the second refresh should keep the data? I mean the user should hit "submit" or "post" or click the button right, but I am so used to hitting that F5...

Comment: TBH I don't care if it does lose it on that F5, but our solution doesn't.  It's been a couple of years since I looked at the code but it does persist it.  Users rarely hit F5 unless it's a list as they are scared of losing their data as much as us developers are.

Comment: @Chris - I made one small change to the code and it now saves the data. You need to shove the value back in TempData on every request:  filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] = filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key]; Now anytime you do a refresh it never reverts to the original state of the page. I still feel it is best to only redirect on success to avoid this. You may have a different opinion and that's fine, but it is not wrong to only redirect on success.

Comment: @Dismissile: I think that's what we do.  I'll find out on Monday - I'm away from the source now.  If everyone had the same opinion, life would be boring :-)  Thanks for the discussion so far - is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Well the obvious question is:

Do you have a file in one of these folders:

```
Views\ControllerName\TaskDetail.aspx
Views\ControllerName\TaskDetail.ascx
Views\Shared\TaskDetail.aspx
Views\Shared\TaskDetail.ascx
```

Where ControllerName is the name of the controller that your Update method is in. That is, if your controller is HomeController, then your folder would be \Views\Home\

**Edit:**
I'm also a little confused about your ModelState.IsValid call, but mostly because you didn't include the TaskDetail controller action. If your model state is not valid wouldn't you want to return the Update view so the user can correct their mistakes and resubmit? Or are they POSTing from the TaskDetail to the Update action?

Comment: Yes they are posting from TaskDetail to Update, TaskDetail is the Get request where multiple form posts can occur, e.g. UpdateTask, AddComment... I do have the view TaskDetail

Comment: Ok where is this exception occurring. Is it failing on the RedirectToAction call or is it failing on the TaskDetail call? Is it failing on an AJAX call or a regular request?

Comment: This is a straightforward FormPost, the error suprising only is caught inside the base controller on Exception (see code above)...

Comment: What I mean is where is the exception originating. Is it because of the RedirectToAction call or is it happeing in the return TaskDetail() call or somewhere else? Does it fail in every scenario or just one path. Might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: What happens is: when the model state is invalid 'return TaskDetail(taskid);' is run, no exceptions occur, the code successfully calls the get request for task details, does all the work and reaches the end of the method without fail, I continue to step into the code and nothing funny happens/ no exception is even thrown, then I reach the base controller OnException I can see the error inside the filtercontext...